# Find list of substrings for a given string that are in the dictionary

Tags: string, algorithm, dictionary, trie

Input given is basically a dictionary (array of strings) and an InputString.

We want to find out all the possible substrings of that string that are in the dictionary.

```
Input:
Dictionary:  ["hell", "hello", "heaven", "ample", "his", "some", "other", "words"]
String: "hello world, this is an example"

Output: ["hell", "hello", "his", "ample"] //all the substrings that are in dictionary.
```

Solution that I can think of is building a trie like structure out of dictionary, and then running following loop

```
for(i= 0 to inputString.length)
   substring = inputString.substring(i,length)
   lookupInTrie(substring) 

lookupInTrie(string)
   this function returns list of complete words from trie that match the prefix of string. 
   i.e, if you pass in string "hello world" to this function and dictionary has word "hell" and "hello" then our lookup will return ["hell","hello"];
```

So if we do not count dictionary->trie conversion. Finding all substrings of a given string that are in dictionary can be done in O(n^2) time.

I want to know if we can optimize this further and reduce the complexity down from n^2.

Comment: Could you give more details, like, an example input and expected output?  When you talk about substrings, are these only prefixes?  Is the dictionary sorted?

Comment: I'm not sure how dictionary sorting matters as I'm converting it to trie anyways but you can assume that if you want. I'll update the question with example.

Comment: If the dictionary is small (say, d elements on average dw characters long) and the string length is l, you could invert the problem: Search the input string for the dictionary word.  When the search algorithm is good (like, Boyer-Moore search), then the resulting complexity is about d*(l/dw).  And you have saved the time for building the trie.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing looks like a perfect spot to use the [Aho-Corasick string-matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), which is essentially an optimized version of the algorithm you're describing above. It works by building a trie from the pattern strings and then running the original string through it, but does so in a way that doesn't require a huge amount of backtracking. The total time complexity is O(m + n + z), where m is the length of the string to search, n is the total length of the pattern strings, and z is the number of matches.

You could also use a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) here. Building a suffix tree for the sentence and then searching for each pattern in it takes time O(m + n + z), where m, n, and z are defined as above, though coding this up from scratch would be pretty tough.